# Tesseract Api OCR Delimeters

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract Api , but i don't know which of is function performing which functionality , i want to change delimeters and use colomn line instead of TAB , We have a page with diffrent Column , and we want to Tesseract wo put newline , when it finds a column line , Pleace Help

Comment: let us know, what have you done..

Comment: i just installed it , All i want is to know , how can i change it's functionality on delimiter ... !